# How do I query this data from postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have these tables

| Unique_iD | land_use_id | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 2013-04-09 |
| 2 | 12 | 2014-03-23 |
| 3 | 13 | 2015-09-21 |
| 4 | 11 | 2016-12-30 |

| land_use_id | land_use_name |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | Single |
| 12 | Reidential |
| 13 | Vacant |

I want to use Postgres to recreate a table using join or sub queries showing the count of each house type categorized by year and groups by house name.

Something like this.

| Name | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Single | 25 | 10 | 34 | 55 |
| Residential | 80 | 12 | 54 | 66 |
| Vacant | 40 | 21 | 34 | 11 |

How do I make this magic happen?

I've tried join and sub queries but I did not get what I'm looking for.

This is what I tried:

```sql
select a.land_use_name,
        count(b.sale_date) as "2013",
        count(c.sale_date) as "2014",
        count(d.sale_date) as "2015"
FROM land_use as a
    JOIN (SELECT land_use_id, sale_date FROM sales_details where date_part('Year', sale_date) = 2013) as b ON b.land_use_id = a.land_use_id
    JOIN (SELECT land_use_id, sale_date FROM sales_details where date_part('Year', sale_date) = 2014) as c ON c.land_use_id = b.land_use_id
    JOIN (SELECT land_use_id, sale_date from sales_details where date_part('Year', sale_date) = 2015) as d ON d.land_use_id = c.land_use_id
group BY a.land_use_name
```

And this is the result I get instead:

| land_use_name | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Single | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| Residential | 26000 | 26000 | 26000 |
| Vacant | 4 | 4 | 4 |

Comment: Please edit to provide a [mcve], including the query you tried, expected vs actual output, errors, etc. Otherwise, this is an incomplete question - it's just the data, leaving the "implement a query" part up to the Community. You mentioned you "tried" something and didn't get the right results - great! include that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional filter() or the extension [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html):

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;

SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    $$ SELECT land_use_name, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sale_date) AS year, COUNT(*)
       FROM sales_details
       JOIN land_use USING(land_use_id)
       GROUP BY land_use_name, year
       ORDER BY land_use_name, year $$,
    $$ SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sale_date) FROM sales_details ORDER BY 1 $$
) AS ct("Land Use Name" TEXT, "2013" INT, "2014" INT, "2015" INT, "2016" INT);
```

You must mention all possible dates as columns, see `"2013" INT`

And when using FILTER():

```
SELECT land_use_name,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sale_date) = 2013) AS "2013",
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sale_date) = 2014) AS "2014",
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sale_date) = 2015) AS "2015",
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sale_date) = 2016) AS "2016"
FROM sales_details
    JOIN land_use USING(land_use_id)
GROUP BY land_use_name
ORDER BY land_use_name;
```